# Cannot autowire bean in MessageListener Class AMQP

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, autowired

Ok. So i have a rabbit configuration class with some constants and I try to add a service to my listenercontainer listener.

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig {

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(HOST);
    connectionFactory.setPort(CONN_PORT);
    connectionFactory.setUsername(USERNAME);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(PASSWORD);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyQueue(replyQueue());
    rabbitTemplate.setCorrelationKey(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public Queue replyQueue() {
    return new Queue(REPLY_QUEUE_NAME);
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_NAME);
    container.setMessageListener(messageListener());
    return container;
}

@Bean
public MessageListener messageListener(){
    return new RabbitListener();
}
```

}

I am trying to inject into the messagelistener which is created in the last lines a service from my project. This triggers an error of cannot autowire field as if the field is not managed by Spring. I did some research and I verified my component scan package and it's set to all the project, I have annotated the rabbitlistener with @Component so I can't really find the mistake or why Spring cannot autowire the field in my listener class. Here is the code.

```
@Component
public class RabbitListener implements MessageListener {
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Autowired
ImagesService imagesService;


@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
//processing message
}
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Would be better if you'd share the full StackTrace, but I suggest you do something like this:

1. Add `@ComponentScan` for your `@Configuration` class and specify there those packages where are your `RabbitListener` and `ImagesService` classes
2. Mark the last two with `@Component` (Yes, I see that on your `RabbitListener`, but it isn't clear where your `ImagesService` and how it is going around it)
3. Than `@Autowire` `RabbitListener` to that `RabbitConfig` instead of `@Bean` for it.

And be careful with the `@Component` and `@Bean` mix: you end up with two bean, if you have `@ComponentScan` for that package, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can i get it straight ... if i declare the bean in my rabbit config as message listener and I instantiate my class annotated with @Component should I get 2 beans instead of one ? For security reasons i cannot share the full stack trace, but the error i am getting is :    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type found for dependency.

Comment: So, there is no `ImagesService` bean to `@Autowire`!

Comment: Well it is, but the Rabbit listener is the only class where I cannot use it for an unknown reason. I also have a RabbitSender class where i can use the service with no problem.

Comment: So, inject it via `setter` and `@Bean` definition for that `RabbitListener` . Sorry, we can't help so much with the whole StackTrace... And yes, you end up with two bean for such a config you are showing right now. And that may cause an issue for that `@Autowired` field  exactly for the `@Bean` case.

Comment: Could there be a possibility that when this bean is constructed imagesService is not instantiated by spring so it cannot be found ?? and how can I delay the instantiation of this bean rabbitSender?

Comment: Try to mark that with `@DependsOn("imagesService")`, but this is a hack and there is really something strange with your app or we see to the wrong way...

Comment: No success with @DependsOn. Thanks for your support maybe we'll find out another ideas. It seems like it's a very odd error.

Comment: Any success on this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, u need to `@Autowire` the `RabbitListener`  bean. Since the `RabbitListener` is a bean that need to be managed by the IOC, since is declared `@Component`, hence @runtime the `RabbitListener` is not in the context, hence autowire it in the config class like so

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig {

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(HOST);
    connectionFactory.setPort(CONN_PORT);
    connectionFactory.setUsername(USERNAME);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(PASSWORD);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyQueue(replyQueue());
    rabbitTemplate.setCorrelationKey(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public Queue replyQueue() {
    return new Queue(REPLY_QUEUE_NAME);
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_NAME);
    container.setMessageListener(rabbitListener); // reference the autowired RabbitListener on this line
    return container;
}

@Autowire
private RabbitListener rabbitListener;
}
```

That should resolve this error.